# JavaScript: Remove all elements with duplicates in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]`

How do I get an array `b = [4, 5]`. How to remove all elements that have duplicates?

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: @DanielBeck nope, not the dupe. That code would return 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Ah, you're right @epascarello, my bad.  CRice has a better dupe target, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to loop over it and see if it exists. Easiest way is to sort and look at its neighbors.

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3];

var noDupes = nums.slice().sort()  //sort it so numbers line up
  .reduce(function(result, c, i, arr){  //loop over the set
  if (c !== arr[i+1] && c !== arr[i-1]) { //see if number is before or after
    result.push(c) //if not, than add it
  }
  return result
}, [])

console.log(noDupes);


var noDupes2 = nums.slice().sort()  
  .filter((c, i, arr) => c !== arr[i+1] && c !== arr[i-1])

console.log(noDupes2);
```

Another solution is to look at indexes without sorting

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3];

var noDupes = nums.filter(( c, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(c) === arr.lastIndexOf(c))
console.log(noDupes)
```

Answer (score 0):

By filtering the ones that the index isn't the same as the last index;

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3];
//console.log(a);
b = a.filter((value) => a.indexOf(value) == a.lastIndexOf(value));
console.log(b)
```

Comment: That's the same as the accepted answer at the duplicate.

Comment: That's true, I must have been in snippet editing mode when this question got marked as dupe. The quick dupe searching I did revealed leaving one occurence there, similar to `SQL DISTINCT`.  Should I remove the answer or leave it here?